# UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't work

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

i want to set an UITapGestureRecognizer to permit to user to add an image as profile. I set the code but, when i touch on the image, nothing happens. Here the code:

```
@IBAction func selezionaFoto(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    fieldNome.resignFirstResponder()

    func selezionaLibreria(action : UIAlertAction!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.Default, animated: true)
        CameraManager.sharedInstance.newImageFromLibraryForController(self, editing: false)
    }

    func scattaFoto(action : UIAlertAction!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.Default, animated: true)
        var circle = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        circle.image = UIImage(named: "overlay")
        CameraManager.sharedInstance.newImageShootForController(self, editing: false, overlay:circle)
    }

    var myActionSheet = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("ACTION_IMAGE_TITLE", comment: ""),
        message: NSLocalizedString("ACTION_IMAGE_TEXT", comment: ""),
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("BUTTON_LIBRARY", comment: ""),
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        handler: selezionaLibreria))

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("BUTTON_SHOOT", comment: ""),
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        handler: scattaFoto))

    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("BUTTON_CANCEL", comment: ""),
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel,
        handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(myActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder() 
    return true
}

func incomingImage(image: UIImage) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
    immagine.image = image
    immagineSelezionata = image
}

func cancelImageSelection() {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
}
```

The first element in the storyboard is the image and then there is the textfield.

Comment: Do you set the property `userInteractionEnabled` to true? For an `UIImageView` the default value is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same issue, I had complicated view hierarchy and the reason why gesture didnt respond to the action, was that one superView was set to isUserInteractionEnabled to false, and as you may know, how gestures received by the app and go to the responder in the chain, is that all UIResponders in this chain should be isUserInteractionEnabled = true, to be delivered to the most top view. I assume that you faced the same situation, so just check all the views in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but it looks like you're just creating a UITapGestureRecognizer on your storyboard and connecting an action to it.

I think you mean to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to a UIImageView, which you can do like this:

```
var myImageview = UIImageView()

var myTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

myImageview.addGestureRecognizer(myTapGestureRecognizer)

myTapGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: Selector("methodName:"))

myImageview.userInteractionEnabled = true

func methodName(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

// do stuff
}
```

Comment: I have an add controller where there are an image and a textfield. I want to set the UITapGestureRecognizer for this image, in this way user can choice an image, or make a photo for his profile.

Comment: Ok so just replace the var myImageView in my example with the imageView in your view controller

Comment: At the top of my code i have: `@IBOutlet var immagine: UIImageView!`

I tried to modify your example, but i have the error: **Expected declaration** on this line: `immagine.addGestureRecognizer(myTapGestureRecognizer)`

**I modified the code in this way:**
`var myTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    
    immagine.addGestureRecognizer(myTapGestureRecognizer)
    
    myTapGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: Selector("selezionaFoto:"))
    
    immagine.userInteractionEnabled = true
    
    @IBAction func selezionaFoto(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
}`

Comment: You need to add the gesture recognizer inside of viewDidLoad and remove your old one.